# Pandas: How to give a unique id for a string when it appears in several rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe looking like this:

```
ner_id  art_id  ner
0       0      emmanuel macron
1       0      paris
2       0      france
3       1      paris
4       0      france
```

I would like to change the column 'ner_id'.

For example, paris appears in the article with id 0 and also 1 (see art_id column).

I would like to only change the column ner_id and give a unique id for paris and not a different id.

I want to do this in the column everytime a word is repeating in the column and give the repeating word the same id.

How can I do it ?

Expected output:

```
ner_id  art_id  ner
    0       0      emmanuel macron
    1       0      paris
    2       0      france
    1       1      paris
    2       0      france
```

I would to give first id of the term everytime a term is being repeated in the next rows.

Comment: ner_id already is unique. Can you include your expected output for this example

Comment: I think what you want is to group by `ner` and assign ids by these groups. If your data frame is called `df`, you could try `df['ner_id'] = df.groupby('ner').ngroup()`.

Comment: @PaulH I updated my post

Comment: Why can't the `ner` column itself serve as the unique identifier?

Comment: @jtorca yes it's a good idea but how can I give the same id for the same word ?

Comment: @PaulH because I have to insert the data into a neo4j database and I would like articles to be link to only one term (one unique node for one term). For example: 2 articles will be linked to paris node. But now I don't have unique terms because they have different ids.

Comment: I've included my comment in the solution below. If you can explain why it doesn't work for you I can update it.

Comment: If you are getting different IDs for the same name using `ngroup`, it may mean that the `ner` column has extra white space for some of the rows.

Comment: Thank you @jtorca I'm going to check in detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just put into an answer. This gives the same ID for the same word.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ner':['emmanuel macron', 'paris', 'france', 'paris', 'france']})

df['ner_id'] = df.groupby('ner').ngroup()

df
```

```
               ner  ner_id
0  emmanuel macron       0
1            paris       2
2           france       1
3            paris       2
4           france       1
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'm going to try on my big dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Use [pandas.factorize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)-

```
df['ner_id'] = pd.factorize(df['ner'])[0]
```

**Timings**

[@jtorca's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64880638/4098013) solution -

```
2.12 ms ± 419 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This one -

```
460 µs ± 45.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Vivek Kalyanarangan it works also

Comment: Never knew about `pd.factorize`. Thanks for the tip. Should be the preferred solution in this scenario.